# centering items withing a float div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm learning CSS and so far managed after many many hours to create a simple layout but still dont know how to center things (text,block,whatever) inside a float:left div. Here's the code i just hope someone might be able to help as im gonna go nuts in a very short time!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            /* */
            border: 1px solid; 
            /* */
            padding-top: 10px;

            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width: 980px;
            height: auto;
        }
        #content {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #content .left {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid; 
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            width:773px;
            float:left;

        }
        #content .right {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-top: 10px;
            width:200px;    
            float:right;
        }

        #content .inside-left {
           text-align: center;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="left">
                <!-- i need every inside-left class center aligned -->
                <div class="inside-left">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>center align</td>
                            <td>damn it</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="right">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

edit: oh and why the **** css is so hard to understand? is it just me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a tiny CSS modification makes a huge difference:

Change this:

```
#content .inside-left {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

To this:

```
#content .inside-left, #content .inside-left > * {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

See the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/8JfNF/1/

This CSS selector, `#content .inside-left > *`, selects all of the direct children (not grandchildren) of the `.inside-left` and applies the same CSS to them.

Comment: @Blender thanks for that, it's working as i wanted to. Where did you learn about `> *` is there any books that explains it? I don't feel like reading the css specification.

Comment: Not joking, but read the table that W3C has to offer. I find it better than any book: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: But most of that comes from practice. You know that `.foo .bar` selects all `.bar` inside of a `.foo`, but `.foo > .bar` selects *only* the `.bar` which are first-generation children of `.foo`.

Comment: I guess you're right and I'm gonna read it as it seems to be a must for understanding CSS.Again thank you for your answers, I'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: No problem. People rarely use W3C, even though they *make* the CSS/HTML standards. If you want a nice and clean tutorial site which sticks to standards, I'd check out HTMLDog: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not tough, i think this is simplest logical thing in world of web...try and learn from some good website..

and there is some suggestion for you..

- better use **class** instead of **id**
- always write 4 basic table property **width, cellpadding, cellspacing and border**
- to horizontal centered the things inside a **td** use `text-align:center;` to make vertical center write `vertical-align:middle`

to learn CSS tricks see my [bookmarks](http://www.delicious.com/6ookmark/css)...this will surely helps u

Comment: I'd argue with that last statement; don't even try using it outside of a table, as you'll save clumps of hair.

Comment: I disagree with all your suggestions.

Comment: @diEcho thank your for your suggestions. `<table>` was just an example, the actual `#content .inside-left` contains 3-5 `<div>`s. I've read about `vertical-align` and that's how I'm aligning images to text. What I don't know if it is ok to have so many `inline-block`.

Comment: @boltClock will you please explain why u r disagree?? and btw its not matter of your disagreetment. correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @Blender i write that inside a  **td**.. that means alwayz inside table

Comment: I'd clarify the cases when `id` is appropriate and when `class` is. I've never heard of the second claim, but that might be because I don't use tables much...

Comment: Because 1) Why is it better to use classes than IDs in this case? 2) You say CSS is not tough, but are suggesting to always write those 4 **HTML attributes** which all have CSS equivalents.

Comment: @Blender: You've not heard of that claim because that has nothing to do with CSS. It was a Web 1.0 thing, before CSS was mainstream.

Comment: Well, it's not remotely funny that you tell someone that CSS is easy yet say to "always write" things that turn out to be HTML attributes that are long deprecated.

Comment: @BoltClock...i just gave him suggestions.... did i write something wrong then tell me?? i always try to taught best practice ..thats why i mention those suggestions

Comment: @diEcho, don't start arguments, please. They're pointless here and serve no purpose. We all know how to code CSS quite well, so don't criticize other because of their questions or comments. This is intended to help the OP learn CSS, not find a champion coder. Teaching old techniques in a HTML4-5 world isn't going to help anyone, so I'd discourage it strongly...

Comment: I just pointed out your mistake at least 2 times. You don't need a third time.